# Add a php script to twig on wordpress

Tags: php, twig

im frecuent user of this forum and always find answers from other users, but this time i need to ask my own question.

At this moment im editing a wp template based on twig that i bought, right now im facing a fancybox gallery which just call the first image, and i need to add the gallery rel to the other images included in the post. i already found the missing code which call the rest of images from the post ID, but i dont know how to express it by the twig structure and incorporate it to the original code of the page

this is the code which display the gallery:

```
{% if wp.get_post_meta(post.ID, '_property_slides', TRUE) %}
    <div class="carousel property">
        <div class="preview">
            <a href="{{ wp.get_post_meta(post.ID, '_property_slides', TRUE).0.imgurl }}" class="fancybox">
                <img src=" {{ wp.get_post_meta(post.ID, '_property_slides', TRUE).0.imgurl }}" alt="">
            </a>
    // the php code expressed on twig goes here //
        </div>
        <!-- /.preview -->

        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                {% for slide in wp.get_post_meta(post.ID, '_property_slides', TRUE) %}
                    {% if loop.first %}
                        <li class="active" >
                    {% else %}
                        <li>
                    {% endif %}
                    <img src="{{ slide.imgurl }}" alt="">
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>

            <a id="carousel-prev" href="#">{{ wp.__('Previous', 'aviators') }}</a>
            <a id="carousel-next" href="#">{{ wp.__('Next', 'aviators') }}</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.content -->
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->
{% endif %}
```

This is the php code i need to implement on twig

```
add_filter(‘wp_get_attachment_link’,'add_gallery_id_rel’);
function add_gallery_id_rel($link){
global $post;
return str_replace(‘<a href’, ‘<a rel=”galeria’. $post->ID .’” href’, $link);
}
```

I really appreciate if you can help me with this (sorry about my weird english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is a filter applied to the regular Wordpress functions, you are using a Twig Wrapper so that code won't work for you.

Try modifying the twig loop.

```
{% for slide in wp.get_post_meta(post.ID, '_property_slides', TRUE) %}
  #... rest of the code
  <a rel="galeria{{ post.ID }}" href="{{ slide.imgurl }}">
    <img src="{{ slide.imgurl }}" alt="">
  </a>
  #... rest of the code
{% endfor %}
```

Skip the first slide using [slice](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html):

```
{% for slide in wp.get_post_meta(post.ID, '_property_slides', TRUE)|slice(1) %}
#... rest of the code same as above
```

Comment: Marco funciona de maravilla, agradezco mucho tu respuesta, me está presentando la siguiente acción ahora, ya muestra la galeria al llamar las imágenes en el fancybox, pero está mostrandolas todas abajo. Como puedo corregir esto? como expresas en una función que le diga que muestre la primera imágen pero oculte las demás. algo como

{% for slide rel="galeria{{ post.ID }}" %}
     {% if first.element %}
        display
     {% else %}

Comment: {% for slide in wp.get_post_meta(post.ID, '_property_slides', TRUE) %}
    <div class="carousel property">
        <div class="preview">
            <a rel="galeria{{ post.ID }}" href="{{ slide.imgurl }}">
                 <img src="{{ slide.imgurl }}" alt="">
             </a>

// condicional del que hablo //

{% for slide rel="galeria{{ post.ID }}" %}
     {% if first.element %}
        display
     {% else %}
        hide
{% endfor %}

// fin del condicional
</div>

Comment: Keep the comments in english here ;) 

I'll update the code in the answer to exclude the first image.

Comment: Hi xmarcos, sorry about my english but i think i didn´t explain myself right. About hidding the images what i need its to show just the first one and hide the other images called for the fancybox gallery. let me share you the link http://goo.gl/cEADb7 as you can see all images form the gallery are showing across the page, the idea its just to show the first one and hide the others.

Let me know if i bother you to much about this solution. thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to have and extra loop ABOVE the code you posted. Post the complete code so i can take a look, maybe in another question to avoid confusion.